# Why is it recommended to use "auto&&" rather than "auto&" in range-for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, standards, idioms

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main
{
    vector<int> coll;
    for (auto&  i : coll) {} // 1
    for (auto&& i : coll) {} // 2
}
```

According to [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

> It is safe, and in fact, preferable in generic code, to use deduction
>   to forwarding reference, for (auto&& var : sequence).

However, I think `2` is completely equivalent to `1`; because `i` is still an lvalue even it is declared as `auto&&`.

**Why is it recommended to use `auto&&` rather than `auto&` in range-for loop?**

Comment: try with `std::vector<bool>`...

Comment: Let's consider `std::vector<bool>`, why is `auto&&` ok and `auto&` not ok?

Comment: The duplicate Q&A has an answer to that question.

Comment: @tuple_cat, no. That Q&A doesn't explain: why is `auto&&` ok and `auto&` not ok?

Comment: It is there, hidden below the "The special case of proxy iterators" heading.

Comment: I've examined the section you pointed out, but I'm still not clear:  why is `auto&&` ok and `auto&` not ok?

Comment: Because `vector<bool>` doesn't return a real reference to a bool but a "fake" one that is hidden behind a [proxy class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference).

Comment: @zett42, I know why `auto&` is not ok; but I don't know why `auto&&` is ok in such a case.

Comment: @xmllmx because this is how c++ works. rvalue don't bind to lvalue reference, but rvalue can bind to rvalue references. More precisely, `auto&&` act as a forwarding reference, so lvalue can be bound too. If you have any questions about this, research and ask another question.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, thanks, i'm clear now.

Comment: If `auto&` would actually work, you would have a dangling reference, because the lvalue's lifetime ends when the body of the for loop is entered. As I see it, `auto&&` basically prolongs the lifetime of the lvalue to the body of the loop.